how to set a shortcut to select a specific Transformation Orientation
I want to set up some transformation shortcuts as I frequently need to switch between Global, View and Gimbal "Transformation Orientations", especially during bone animations.
I see that the 3d View "Transformation Orientations" have a single shortcut key (that I can change from numpad-+, which only works if I'm hovering over the drop-down.

I bet there's some magic you good looking people could share.
Again I'd like to select a bone and shift between Global and View as I move and rotation and also Gimbal to look at single dimension transformations.

Can't you use the pie menu which is initiated with the ',' comma hotkey?
